# Derivative with respect to $x$ of $\frac{1}{\int^a_x{f(x')}dx'}$

Tags: calculus

I would like to know the solution to: $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\int^a_x{f(x')}dx'},$$ please, where $a$ is some constant.

I know that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int^a_x{f(x')}dx' = -f(x)$$ but the inverse is less clear to me.

My attempt got me this far: $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\cdot\frac{\int^{x+h}_{x}f(x')dx'}{(\int^{a}_{x+h}f(x')dx')\cdot(\int^{a}_xf(x')dx')} $$ but I am not sure how to evaluate this limit.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Call $F(x)=\int_x^af(t)\,dt$, and call $G(x)=\frac{1}{F(x)}$, and assume everything is nicely defined (say $f>0$ and is continuous). You have already mentioned how to calculate $F'(x)$. Do you see how (chain rule and power rules) to calculate $G'(x)$? Your approach amounts to reproving the chain and power rules in a special case (and also FTC). If you want to continue though, put the $\frac{1}{h}$ in the numerator. Do you see how to simplify now?

Comment: Why don't you just use the formula to derive a quotient?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they helped me reach the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you know how to find the derivative $g'(x)$ for a given function $g(x)$, the quotient rule of derivatives tells you that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{-g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}\;.
$$

Alternatively, you can also apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_x^a f(x) dx \right) ^{-1} = - \frac{1}{\left( \int_x^a f(x) dx \right)^2} \frac{d}{dx} \left[ - \left( \int_a^x f(x) dx \right)\right]
$$

Where I exchanged limits of integration and added a minus sign.

Now applying the fundamental theorem of calculus in the last derivative, you obtain:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_x^a f(x) dx \right) ^{-1} = \frac{f(x)}{\left( \int_x^a f(x) dx \right)^2}
$$